# Как web-приложение может перехватить номер телефона входящего звонка?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, веб-программирование

Есть база клиентов с номерами телефонов. Клиенты могут быть одноразовые, в мобильный телефон не записываются.

Стоит задача:  при входящем звонке определить номер звонящего и высветить на экране телефона информацию о нем из БД. С чего начать? Куда "рыть"?

Comment: 1) Веб приложение находится где? В телефоне?
2) Это что браузер отображающий некий удаленный сайт или ваш `WebView`, который вы контролируете?

Comment: у части пользователей сервиса используются IPhone, поэтому желательно реализовать это на вебе

Comment: Ладно, я пас... ТС сам не понимает свой вопрос :)

Comment: в телефоне, броузер отображает сайт, который я сам и создаю, БД находится в интернете, с запросом к mysql нет вопросов, использую jquery, ajax, php

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

В iOS без джеилбрейка даже нативным программам это не дано, не то что какому-то сайту.

В Android можно получить номер телефона звонящего, но снова же, не каким-то сайтом. Вы можете создать программу-обертку с WebView, в которой будете получать номер телефона и передавать через JS. Но это тоже не то, что хотите. Да и стоит ли оно того?

Так что никак.